# What would happen if Luke Cage needed surgery?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, the-defenders-2017, luke-cage

In *Marvel's The Defenders* we can clearly see that the Iron Fist can damage Luke Cage's jaw. If he had broken his jaw, sliced some of his flesh, broken a tooth etc., could Luke Cage have gotten proper medical attention? Could an anaesthetic needle, stitches or a dental drill help him?

Is there any mention of something like this in the comics?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Claire has performed surgery on him at least twice, once in Jessica Jones and once in Luke's own series.

Comment: If the plot requires Luke Cage to have surgery, a person with the proper surgical skills and tools will arrive.  This includes someone with something that will allow the breaking of Cage's skin, or something that will allow surgery without breaking the skin.

Comment: Claire knows how to soften his skin enough to perform surgery on him, I believe. As seen on *Luke Cage*.

Comment: In the comics, Luke required surgery in an Avengers story by Brian Bendis (who can be credited for Luke's prominence over the past 15 years or so, without which there probably wouldn't be a *Luke Cage* TV show). The team had been affected by something that turned off superpowers (I think in the same fight where Luke was injured), and retrieved and repaired said device so Luke could be operated on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much would happen.

In JJ (Jessica Jones), Claire needed to reduce intracranial pressure because Jessica managed to injure him enough to knock him out.  She had to go through the eye socket to get there.

EDIT:

In the Luke Cage series:

> They showed that bathing him in the right
>  kinds of boiling acid will loosen his cells enough to cut between them
>  and pull an alien metal bullet out.

Comment: How long did they have to boil him?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd, I don't recall the specific amount of time but it worked.  It was in an episode near the end of the season.

Answer (score 11):

In the Luke Cage series, he is shot by a bullet created with Chitauri metal fragments that is able to pierce his skin, so presumably surgical equipment made with exotic materials such as this might suffice.

In any case, he undergoes surgery later in the series to remove said bullet fragments. To do this the original experiment that gave him his powers is recreated, and he is submerged in an acid bath to soften his skin enough to open it back up with a scalpel.

Comment: I love the villain's thinking here. "He's immune to bullets, how can we kill him?" "I've got it- we use a SUPER BULLET!"